# racket get two objects in an array

Tags: for-loop, racket

In an assignment that I have I have to find the biggest gap in an array.

To do so I get 5 digits and want to pass every digit and check it comparing to the next digit.

I fount that the 'for' works something like this:

```
> (for/list ([i '(1 2 3)])
    (* i i))
'(1 4 9)
```

The question is how to get not 'i' position but the '('i' + 1)' position. In java the way will be something like this:

```
    public void gettingSecondIndex(int a,int b,int c,int x,int y){
        int[] abc = {a,b,c,x,y};
        int index, secondIndex;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < abc.length - 1 ; i++){
            index = abc[i]; // this is the index
            secondIndex = abc[i+1]; // this is what I am looking how to do in Racket
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with *lists* in Racket, try to forget about the indexes (they're not arrays!). You can get the desired effect with something like this:

```
(define (getting-second-index lst)
  (for/list ([n1 lst]
             [n2 (rest lst)])
    (list n1 n2)))
```

Now that you have the contiguous pairs, proceed to process them as you wish:

```
(getting-second-index '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5))
```

Comment: A `for` comprehension will stop when the shortest sequence runs out, so the `drop-right` is unnecessary and wasteful. :-)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!
ummm I am really new to Racket so if you can explain me with commits the lines so I will be able to understand more I will be happy :)

Comment: @Tomer it's simple: n1 iterates over the list and n2 over the same list _without the first element_, then the body of the loop pairs one element from one list with the element in the other that's in the same position. We do this until the second list runs out of elements.